# Getting BLOB from JSON Object in Android

Tags: android, json, blob

I want to read a data from php and I used JSON Object to get the data. And one of the data I want to get from the database is BLOB. I tried by myself with the following code.

```
products = new JSONArray(getJSONUrl(url));
// looping through product
for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObj = products.getJSONObject(i);
    try {
        placeName = jsonObj.getString(String.valueOf(TAG_PlaceName));
        placeDesc = jsonObj.getString(TAG_PlaceDesc);
        Blob blob = (Blob) jsonObj.get(TAG_placeIcon);
        byte[] byteBlob = blob.getBytes(0, (int) blob.length());
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteBlob, 0, byteBlob.length);
        rowItems.add(new RowItem(placeName, placeDesc, bmp));
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

- RowItem is the class that I keep the data.

Can anyone point out what is wrong in my code. I tried to look around for like many hours but I still can't find a solution.

By the way when I tried running the app, It seems that UI doesn't have any problem. Only that the listview that I use to show the data seems to have nothing in it.

Comment: Does it throw exception?

Comment: there are no errors at all

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            String id = params[0];
            String add = "http://user localhost/ImageUpload/getImage.php?id="+id;
            URL url = null;
            Bitmap image = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(add);
                image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return image;
        }
```